# In my case, when I mv a symbolic link, the content are really moved

Tags: symlink

I move a symbolic link and the content is moved! I heard that symbolic link is just an alias of some physical content. So I do not understand how my directory workspace5 is moved!

How is it possible? Thank you for your idea.

For info. , I am using Mac Os. Here is the command line I typed from console.

```
ln -s /Users/home/Documents/workspace5 ln.workspace5
mv ln.workspace5/ ~
```

The result: the whole directory  /Users/home/Documents/workspace5 is moved to ~

Comment: can you please explain some more? Why do you say the contents move? are they moving from the location at /Users/homeDeocuments/workspace5 to another location?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the trailing slash in the first argument of `mv`.  Use `mv ln.workspace5 ~` instead of `mv ln.workspace5/ ~` if you just want to move the symlink.